# Why doesn't Java support socks4?

Tags: java, proxy, socks

Take this code into consideration:

```
    Proxy p = new Proxy(Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress(proxyURL, port));
    try {

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection(p);
        System.out.println(urlConn.getContent());
        int ping = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
        System.out.println(proxyURL+ ":" +port+ " ... works as SOCKS, ping: " +ping);           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have verified though Wireshark that this doesn't work on a valid socks4 proxy. At this time these are valid socks4 ONLY proxy servers:

```
92.241.233.75:1080
58.214.5.162:1080
222.51.38.138:1080
121.8.124.42:1080
220.179.61.62:1080
75.125.63.178:1080
201.59.145.141:1080
117.20.60.144:1080
```

Yet, feed it a valid socks5 proxy and it works fine:

```
    62.243.224.179
```

Comment: Which JDK are you using?

Comment: Java-6-openjdk is the one I'm using. Kind of new to linux/ubuntu plus I actually haven't been doing a lot of java lately either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/90020/java-socks4-client).  I didn't test it, but sounds like it'll work (but not an ideal solution).